# Wifi router that has a *button* to turn wifi signal off?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, power-consumption

Anobody knows about any wifi routers that have a **button** (or switch) to turn the wifi signal off?

BTW: there are a few reasons I can think of why one would want to do this but not turn of the complete router:

- save energy / gain security, when no one is home, but you still want your wired network to be operational to have access to e.g. a NAS
- turn off the wifi signal when you go to bed because the basestation is close to your bed and you're are worried about too much RF signals slowly destroying your brain
- make sure children upstairs can't access the internet instead of doing their homework

The whole point of having a button instead of a software solution would be that anybody could do it, including your non-technical wife for example.

Comment: I have not seen one of these in a long time. Is there a reason you don't want to turn off the whole router, just Wifi?

Comment: Maybe he's got some machines connected via wire.

Comment: Given the tag "energy" (much appreciated!) I wonder if switching of Wifi actually saves energy for all such devices.

Comment: I do have weird dreams of surfing the internet when my wireless is on - maybe that's that.

Comment: I've edited my question with some justification...

Comment: I realise you might not have been totally serious about reason 2, but there's no evidence that wifi signals harm the brain or that they can be detected by so called "sensitives".

Comment: @Arjan: the typical RF output power of a basestation is 15-20 dBm, which corresponds to 100mW (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm). So, indeed, even with some extra mW overhead, that wouldn't exactly count as 'saving energy'...

Comment: @ChrisF: actually I am serious about it. My router *was* placed on a 2m high cupboard directly under the location of my bed one floor higher. With a baby in the house, I can assure you, you tend to be on the safe side and not have an RF-source 1m from where he is sleeping. There's no study yet detailing the impact of 30 years of wifi signals when sleeping :-)

Comment: @Rabarberski : Have you considered the alternative thinking that your kid might gain a few IQ points because of that? :P

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that the idea of turning the whole thing off was thought of. I know I've made that sort of thinking mistake before.

Comment: As for *make sure children upstairs can't access the internet* -- I hope their computers cannot hook up to some unsecured network from some neighbour then. ;-) (Which by itself may impose some security threats, if these neighbours would like to listen into the communications, but well I guess you considered that already as well.)

Answer (score 6):

Some versions of the Linksys WRT54G have a button on the front (under the Cisco logo), initially used by the Linksys firmware for SES (easier setup of wireless security).

Using the alternative DD-WRT firmware, the button can be remapped to switch on/off the wireless radio.

Unfortunately I'm not sure it's possible with the DD-WRT "mini" that you have to install as of the versions 5+ of the WRT54G (due to the smaller ROM/Flash they put in them).

Comment: Refer: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SES_Button.  SES -> Linksys, AOSS -> Buffalo, EZ-SETUP -> Asus.  Not an off-the-shelf solution since you have to install DD-WRT, but it's an option.

Comment: Only the first few (i think v1, v2) versions of the WRT54G has the SES button... the rest does not have that feature anymore.

Comment: I have a v5 and it has the SES button.

Comment: WRT54GL has the SES button as well. More info on this can be found on the dd-wrt website though... Only issue I have with it so far is that my SES button stays on whether the wifi is on or off... which is confusing.
Edit: You can put cron jobs in the DD-WRT firmware to turn off your signal at night if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

Back before (nearly) all home routers had wifi built-in I had a setup that let me do exactly this.

A (4-port+external) ethernet router connected to my broadband and a separate wireless router plugged into one of the ethernet ports on the back (that just passed DNS/DHCP through to the main router).

Any non-technical person can then switch off the wireless box, or even just pull the plug out of the wall to disable the wireless.

In your case, if you've already got a router, just permanently switch off the WiFi on that, and then plug a cheap, dumb wireless AP into it.

Comment: +1, @Rabarberski, since you're considering buying hardware, this might be the easiest way.  An AP + disable wireless on the router.

Comment: In addition to this you can also buy a digital 'timer' that will turn on/off your wireless router at set times. For example, you can have it turn off at 9pm and turn on again at 6am.. My timer actually has 2 on and 2 off settings. I think I bought 2 digital timers on ebay for $15 a year ago or so.. just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this feature in some Netgear wireless routers before... let me search...

There ya go : the [DG834G](http://www.netgear.com/Products/RoutersandGateways/WirelessGRouters/DG834G.aspx) has it. Under Features :

"WiFi on/off switch to turn off wireless signals"

Comment: ...would have been nice if that stated "to save energy". Some (or all?) Netgear routers have this flashing Christmas-tree-like LED lighting that makes me feel they don't care to much about saving energy...

Comment: This "christmas-tree-like LEDs" can be turned off in the settings. After that, it's nice and quiet. Even quieter than my current router (a Zyxel, which illuminates the whole room...)