# Wireless router (or AP) with hardware on/off switch for WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Basically the same question as the locked [Wifi router that has a *button* to turn wifi signal off?](https://superuser.com/questions/38345/wifi-router-that-has-a-button-to-turn-wifi-signal-off) or [Wireless router (or AP) with hardware on/off switch for WLAN](http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/wireless-router-ap-hardware-off-switch-wlan-18142.html) from wirelessfourms.org in 2007.

My wife found [Is Your Health on the Line](http://health.yahoo.net/rodale/WH/is-your-health-on-the-line) which seemed like a little too scare tactic about the dangers of RF energy, but suggested you turn off your router when not in use.  Let's not debate the dangers of RF, because that appears to be what got the previous question locked.

I have hard wired devices that need to be connected (e.g. TiVo), so I'd like to find a wireless router that has a physical off switch for the wireless network.  Other possibilities are to block the signal by putting a tin can over the antenna or disable the wireless in software on my existing router, and buy a second device for wireless which can be unplugged.  Since my existing router is a circa 2003 [Dell TrueMobile 2300 Wireless Broadband Router](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/p57205/), I could probably use an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open-source [Tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato/) runs on Linksys WRT54-G/GL/GS, Buffalo WHR-G54S/WHR-HP-G54 routers, and some other routers with broadcom chipsets. On routers with an extra hardware button for Secure Easy Setup (SES) such as the WRT54-GL, it allows you to set that button to perform a different action, including toggling the wireless radio on and off. If you were to upgrade to a WRT-54GL, you could install Tomato and set the button up to that. It's possible that [DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) may support this feature on some routers as well, but I haven't personally observed it.

All that being said, you might be better spending your money on something with a more directly positive impact on your health — there's EM radiation everywhere, and even if you turn off your WiFi radio, your neighbors' WiFi and the local cell tower and who knows what else will still be there.

Comment: Also found a WiFi Toggle for OpenWrt - http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wifitoggle

Answer (score 1):

A few Netgear wireless routers, such as the WNR2000v3, have a "wireless on/off button".

"The Wireless On/Off button allows customers to turn off the wireless portion of their router/gateway when not in use. A wireless router consumes up to 30% less power with the wireless turned off, then with it on. With the Wireless On/Off button, it is simple for our customers to turn off the wireless when they are sleeping at night, or at work in the daytime. Turning off wireless also has a security benefit, since it prevents anyone from hacking into the wireless network."

Note that the original WNR2000, now called v1, does *not* have such a switch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to just suggest that you not cave on this issue.  Whether or not it's real aside, if you're scared of the RF emissions you're doomed anyway.  RF is *everywhere* now — you're neighbor's wifi, cell phones, cordless home phones, police/emergency signals, TV, even your microwave oven all use some sort of RF, and much of it is a *lot* more powerful than your wifi.

But I just said tempted.  I know a geek wanting an excuse for an upgrade when I spot one.  With that in mind, I haven't seen a consumer router with that feature on the market in a long time.  The closest I think you can do right now is a nice router that can handle dd-wrt, which my quick research suggests may support [mapping a different button to do this instead](https://superuser.com/questions/38345/wifi-router-that-has-a-button-to-turn-wifi-signal-off) — perhaps an "easy setup" (or WPS) button.

Comment: FYI, you link is a copy of the same locked superuser question I referred to in my question.